# SQL Server Agent Job called a Stored Procedure that used Linked Server did not work

Tags: stored-procedures, proxy, credentials, linked-server, sql-agent-job

I have a stored procedure that uses linked server:

- The linked server was created pointing to the Source Database server and Security is "Be made using the login's current security context"
- The credential was created using an AD service account
- The proxy was created with a check on the "Operating system (CmdExec) "
- The stored procedure used the linked server bame in the insert/select command.   The stored procedure worked well when I executed it within SSMS.

However when I run the stored procedure from SQL Server Agent Job step, using SQLCMD, it did not work.

Here is the example of my stored procedure:

```
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LINKED_SERVER] 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyDatabaseName.dbo.MyTableName
        SELECT * 
        FROM [linkedservername].SourceDatabaseName.dbo.SourceTableName
END
GO
```

After creating the stored procedure, I executed it from SSMS - stored procedure.  I worked well.

`MyTableName` had data inserted from the `SourceTableName`.

I then created a SQL Server Agent job with two steps:

- Step #1: Run a stored procedure, truncate data from `MytableName`
- Step #2: Run the "TEST_LINKED_SERVER" stored procedure, update data to `Mytablename`, by insert data from the linked server/database/table on another server using the linked server.

Step #2 was setup as follows:

- Type: Operating system (CmdExec)
- Run as:  ProxyName
- Command:  SQLCMD -Q "EXEC dbo.TEST_LINKED_SERVER"

The job completed successfully. However `MytableName` did not have any data. It is empty. Data was not inserted to `MyTableName`.

Would you have any idea? Do I need to update my SQLCMD? And how?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it worked: 
SQLCMD -E -S MyServerName -D MyDatabaseName -Q "EXEC dbo.TEST_LINKED_SERVER"